# waitpid in infitine wait state after PTRACE_ATTACH

Tags: c++14, ptrace, google-breakpad

I have integrated **Google-Breakpad** in my C++ application. Now, I am deliberately crashing the application but it hangs-up in my Ubuntu i686 system. I have to put `printf` everywhere in Breakpad to check where exactly it is hanging. So, in breakpad, a clone child process is being created and in that process `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL)` followed by `waitpid(pid, NULL, __WALL)` syscall is being called on every thread. With one particular thread waitpid is entering in infinite wait state and I then have to deliberately kill the application.

Does anyone knows why exactly this is happening? Why with this one particular thread `waitpid()` is going in infinte wait state? Is there any solution for the same?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to give more information. It is not clear what you're asking. I think the break-pad support forums is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad for stack overflow, and really belongs in the break-pad support forums.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh I have already asked in the breakpad forum(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-breakpad-discuss/2Ajlsnvkjpw). And I think I gave all the required information. Just consider it as normal problem without breakpad thing. I just need to know that what are the reason that `waitpid` is going in infinite wait state after `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH..)` call for one particular thread? Its not like that no one used ptrace and waitpid combination.

Comment: Great idea. then if it's a normal question, feel free to post an MCVE. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In general, PTRACE_ATTACH does not guarantee that a process will have anything to report. After PTRACE_ATTACH, waitpid will trigger only if one of two things happen:

- The debugee receives a signal.
- The debugee exists.

Some things are tantamount to one of those things. For example, if the debugee calls `execve`, then after a successful execution the kernel makes it appear *as if* the debugee received a `TRAP` signal.

If none of those situations happen, there is no reason for `PTRACE_ATTACH` to do anything at all.

If you want `waitpid` to return (say, because you want to change the debugee's state), then simply send a signal to the thread after calling `PTRACE_ATTACH`. This will guarantee that the thread have something to tell you.